# Program only adds the first row of the matrix (and messes up the other rows)

Tags: c

I'm trying to do some simple addition in a 3x3 matrix

```
int a[3][3], b[3][3], i, j, r[3][3], q, p, mul;
//matrix A
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf("masukan matrix A baris %d ", i + 1, j + 1);
        scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    }
}
//matrix B
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf("masukan matrix B baris %d ", i + 1, j + 1);
        scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
    }
}
//result
printf("matrix A \n");
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf(" %d ", a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("matrix B \n");
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf(" %d ", b[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    puts("1.  addition");
    puts("2.  Transpose");
    puts("3.  exit");
    printf("choice ");

    scanf("%s", &choice);
    switch (choice) {
    case '1': {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                r[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    printf(" %d \t", r[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    } break;
}
```

[and i got this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISHfw.png)

as you can see it only adds the first row of the 2 matrices.

I'm fairly new to C and i have no idea the workaround for this problem
any help would be appreciated

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave a complete example including showing how you initialized and allocated the arrays `a`, `b` and `r`. The issue is likely related to how those arrays were allocated.

Comment: You're also missing a closing brace on the outer for loop where you do the addition.

Comment: @BillLynch i tried to post the whole code earlier but it says the whole post seems to be a code or smth, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Sending your code through a [code formatter](http://format.krzaq.cc) shows that you are missing a closing brace at two locations:

#### Location 1

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    printf(" %d ", b[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  // missing a closing brace here.
  puts("1.  addition");
```

#### Location 2

```
      for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          r[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
      // missing a closing brace here.
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf(" %d \t", r[i][j]);
          }
```

Comment: you are an actual wizard, i actually have the first 'missing brace' idk why it didn't get copied on my post. As for the 2nd brace i seems to have misplaced it and its now fixed. thank you so much